Understanding stochastic integration with semimartingale as integrator: The locally bounded variation part.
Let $X_t = M_t + A_t$ be a semimartingale with continuous paths, and  M is a local martingale, and A is a process with paths locally of bounded variation.
The book I'm reading, states that we can compute $$\int^t_0 f(s) d X_s = \int^t_0 f(s) dM_s + \int^t_0 f(s) dA_s$$ when $$\int^{\infty}_0 f^2(s) d \langle M \rangle_s + \int^{\infty}_0 |f(s)| |dA_s|<\infty$$
Lebesgue-Stieltjes integration for process $A$
I'm trying to understand what $dA_s$ means. After some searching, I found this answer in Math.SE, and this wikipage.
From what I gather, for $\int^b_a f(x) dg(x)$, with $g$ a monotone right-continuous function, there's a unique lebesgue-stieltjes measure determined by $\mu_g((a,b]) = g(b)-g(a)$ for all such real intervals. When $g$ is the identity function, we have the Lebesgue measure, and this integration coincides with the Lebesgue integration. Otherwise,
$$\int^b_a f(x) dg(x) = \int^b_a f(x) \mu_g(dx)$$.
For the case of when $g$ is of bounded variation (BV), then we can define $g_1 = V_a^xg$ (total variation of $g$ in $(a,x]$) and $g_2 = g_1-g$, and in this case both $g_1,g_2$ are monotone non-decreasing, and we can compute the integral as
$$\int^b_a f(x) dg(x) = \int^b_a f(x) \mu_{g_1}(dx)-\int^b_a f(x) \mu_{g_2}(dx)$$

How does this exactly relate to $\int^b_a f(s) dA_s$?

One difficulty is $A(s,\omega)$ being a function that for a specific happening $\omega$ may be a different locally BV function.
I think that in this integral, we seeing $A$ as function $t\rightarrow A(t,\omega)$ only, where we're keeping $\omega$ fixed. This would also allow us to consider the same BV function (given $\omega$).
In this way, we could $\int^b_a f(s) dA_s = \int^b_a f(x) \mu_{A_1}(dx)-\int^b_a f(x) \mu_{A_2}(dx)$.
However, there's also another difficulty for me, here. In the previous formula, I'm assuming implicitly we know a sequence of stopping times which make the process $A$ of BV. So, instead of $dA_s$ we should put $dA_{s\wedge T_n}$ for a given $n$. Correct?

What's $|dA_s|$?

At first, I thought we had a signed measure, and we we're dealing with the Hahn-Jordan measure decomposition theorem, but based on what I've written above, I think we're dealing with a simple absolute value (or modulus).

Indeed, for each $\omega$ you get a different measure $\mu_g$. So the integral can be defined path-by-path: i.e. for a fixed $\omega$
$$\left( \int_a^b f(s) dA_s \right)(\omega) = \int_a^b f(\omega, s) d\mu_g(\omega)$$
where $\mu_g (\omega)$ is the signed measure associated to the path $A_s(\omega)$. Indeed, this integral is defined up to a stopping time $T_n$.
For your other question: the integral against $|dA|$ corresponds to the integral against the total variation of $\mu_g$. Notice that if $\mu_g$ is a signed measure, then it is the difference of two positive measures: $\mu_g = \mu_g^+ - \mu_g^-$. The total variation is the measure $|\mu_g| = \mu_g^+ + \mu_g^-$

Thanks José. By the way, any good bibliography for this? ;)

@ An old man in the sea : Hopefully Jose will reply but this looks pretty good ( doesn't cover local marthingales ) as far as references.  In general, her teaching material is really well written but I don't know if any of her material covers what you asked. https://cims.nyu.edu/~holmes/teaching/asa19/handout_Lecture7_2019.pdf

@Anoldmaninthesea. the link shared by Mark is a good introduction. For a more detailed treatment, I like Continuous Martingales and Brownian Motion by Revuz and Yor

@markleeds it seems that to access that resource, one needs some special credential...

yeah. something must have changed since I accessed it last week. Let me see if I can get there some other way. If I can, I'll let you know.

I wrote her an email so maybe it wll get fixed. Thanks for heads up.

She changed schools so the updated link is here. https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~holmescerfon/teaching/asa22/handout-Lecture7_2022.pdf
